# What is the difference between wso2 identity server and CAS?

Tags: wso2, cas, wso2-identity-server

Recently I learned about wso2 Identity server, it seems it can cover all the functions of CAS(Central Authentication Service) which I am familiar with.

I have the following 3 questions:

1. what is the difference between  Identity server and CAS?
2. Can Identity server and CAS work together in one system in order to use their respective advantages.
3. Can we really only use Identity server instead of using Identity server and CAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much familiar with CAS, but with Identity Server. So following information is based on that.

1. As I know CAS is an authentication service. Identity Server(IS) addresses a much more broad scope of authentication, authorization, delegation etc.. with a framework for 'System & User Identity Management'. All the features are listed here. 100% open source. http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/.
2. If you want to use CAS for authentication and use other features from IS, it's possible with the provided extension points of IS.
3. WSO2 Identity Server provides sophisticated security and identity management of enterprise web applications, services, and APIs. So you will be able to rely on IS. But to confirm that,exact required functionality should be analysed. (Like whether you want functionality of Single Sign On, fine grained authorization... )